# Node React structure without view engine

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm new to node. I was using `express-handlebars` as my `view-engine`, but now I've added React and I understood that I no longer require handlebars. The problem that I'm having is that in order to get to the `index.html` page, without handlebars, I had to use

`app.use(express.static('./public'));`

Everything gets rendered from react, but what if I want to do some other things when the user goes to the index page like

```
app.get("/",function(req,res){
    console.log("connected");
});
```

If I add the get request after exporting the static files, the `console.log` never gets called. If I use it before, it does get called, but I can see the page loading forever. How should I structure the application now that I'm using react and I don t have a `view engine` anymore?

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, if you don't want to render anything to the user, you should turn your function into a middleware :

```
app.get("/",function(req,res, next){
    console.log("connected");
    next();
});
```

and put it before the `app.use(express.static('./public'));`

However, if you want to do actual logic with return values and such, I would suggest that you setup some kind of API that you request using Ajax from the client.

Comment: And how would a post work? Where would I add that? Would it be the same as adding get using next();?

Comment: Yes. But, as mentionned in my answer, you should give us more details about what you **really** want to achieve in place of the `console.log`. So that we can suggest a *real-case* solution to the underlying issue.

Comment: For now I want to create a chat app cause it would help me learn the most. I've already added socket.io, but I changed to react, cause I want to learn that too. And I want to understand the structure I have to use now that I don't have a view engine anymore. I mean when I'm going to send a message, don t I need a app.post to receive it?

Comment: Socket.io is totally independant from Express. You don't have to change your routes in any way. Take a look at the [official chat tutorial](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) and you'll have a better understanding of the way to set this up.

Answer (score 0):

You can check my repository 
https://github.com/kennethmervin01/react-node-production

it's a boilerplate to serve react app in node.js/express

then check my code inside app.js

You just need to copy  the production build of your react app inside the react folder

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../react")));
app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../react", "index.html"));
});
```